# Odoo - How to Modularize XML Field

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-14

I have a nested field in my XML file and I want to modularize it. For example, I have a model with the field `One2many`. When I call the `One2many` field in XML, I need to provide the form & tree view.

```
<!-- Parent Form -->
<record id="view_rm_reservation_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">rm.reservation.form</field>
    <field name="model">rm.reservation</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <sheet>
                ...
                ...
                <!-- One2many -->
                <field name="order_line_ids">
                     <!-- One2many Tree -->
                    <tree create="1">
                        ...
                        ...
                    </tree>
                    
                    <!-- One2many Form -->
                    <form create="0">
                        ...
                        ...
                    </form>
                </field>
                ...
                ...
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

I want to put the `One2many Tree` and `One2many Form` into a separate file. How I can do this? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is possible. Just create a form and tree view for the model behind that `one2many` field and then "call" those views on the model of that field.

Presumptions: You have a form view `my_module.view_sub_model_form` and tree view `my_module.view_sub_model_tree` for the model behind the `one2many` field. The field itself is like in your example `order_line_ids`.

So you just do the following to use the views:

```xml
<field name="order_line_ids"
    context="{'tree_view_ref': 'my_module.view_sub_model_tree',
              'form_view_ref': 'my_module.view_sub_model_form'}" />
```

When creating new "basic views" (not extending existing ones) keep an eye on the priority field of the views, because that one is important for the order of retrieving views by Odoo. Not setting it will lead to value `16`, and should be fine in most situations. When using such special views only for one2many fields, i would set it atleast one higher to `17`.

```xml
    <record id="view_sub_model_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sub.model.form</field>
        <field name="model">sub.model</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="17" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: Wow, this is working. But I remove the `mode` and `priority` and everything is fine

Comment: Yes, priority is not needed everytime. I will remove mode, because that would be only needed if you want to create a new basic view and also inheriting from an existing one.

Comment: Thank you, can you answer my other questions please, I have a lot of questions regarding Odoo. And 1 month from now, probably I will make a lot of Odoo questions

Comment: Sorry, but i can't answer everything ;-)

Comment: Ok no problem bro